# Arduino driver for lots of high power LEDs

Tags: arduino, power-supply, led, high-current

This is my first Arduino/electronics project and I am a little bit confused about the components I need to handle huge amount of currents and the circuit.

I want to have full control of 32 (maybe 40) 6-pin 3W RGB LEDs from an Arduino Uno. By saying full control I mean to be able to adjust the brightness of each led independently.

LED specs: 
DC Forward Voltage (VF) : RED:2.3-2.6V,GREEN:3.4-3.8V,BLUE:3.4-3.8V 
DC Forward Currect (IF) : 350mA per channel, ~1050mA total

If all LEDs are on we need 32 amps at least. Of course I'll need an external power supply. I was thinking of a common computer PSU but I'm not sure if that's enough. Any other suggestions?

Other power issues that I have to solve:

- How can I provide the appropriate voltage to each LED color from a PSU? Is there any better way instead of buying a DC to DC converter for each LED x3 channels?
- I'll use shift registers to control all led channels. How should I connect them and with what type of transistors and be sure that I won't burn anything?

I've searched around the internet about similar stuff but I got confused since there lots of electronic components around the circuit and so many ways to connect them.

Any schematic and details about the components I'll need will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use dedicated LED driver chips?

Comment: 40 LEDs and 32 amps, what? If you have a power supply that can pass sufficient current without dropping voltage you won't need but maybe 1 amp (20mA*40 + margin) unless these are really current-hungry LEDs. Also, most projects I've seen like this [multiplex](http://www.instructables.com/id/Multiplexing-with-Arduino-and-the-74HC595/) the LEDs so no more than a single LED is on at any given time. If you want to also control the brightness of each LED you are going to have to use PWM, which is another added complexity. I would go with a dedicated driver as stated above.

Comment: @ApollonDigital: Do you have a link to the LED data sheet?

Comment: @sherrellbc 3 Watt LEDs have actually become quite common-place especially with the LED house lighting market taking off. http://www.superbrightleds.com/moreinfo/component-leds/vollong-3w-rgb-high-power-led/899/2214/?utm_source=googlebase&utm_medium=base&utm_content=VL-RGB&utm_campaign=GoogleBaseChild&gclid=CjkKEQjww6SdBRDls9vxsf7EoM0BEiQART_xPkEnmGIV9skew5DuAZwCeqgKNW7yBFI52faMXxj4Tybw_wcB

Comment: Quick tip: (old) ATX power supplies (the ones used in computers) make for great, low cost, worry-free high current power supplies.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't know how they work and how I should connect them. Can you give me an example circuit with a specific chip? How much they cost?
Thanks

Comment: The datasheet will have the appropriate circuit for the chip. The vendors' parametric search tools will help you find an appropriate chip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> LED specs:  DC Forward Voltage (VF) :
> RED:2.3-2.6V,GREEN:3.4-3.8V,BLUE:3.4-3.8V
> DC Forward Current (IF) : 350mA per channel, ~1050mA total
>
> If all LEDs are on we need 32 amps at least.
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> How can I provide the appropriate voltage to each led color from a PSU?

You don't do it that way; you apply the current needed to supply the brightness you want, or you apply the maximum current and PWM - Pulse Width Modulate - each LED to get the apparent brightness you want.

> I'll use shift registers to control all led channels. How should I connect them and with what type of transistors and be sure that I won't burn anything?

Like this:

[image]

The transistors are logic-level N channel MOSFETs and they should have a drain-to-source voltage rating > 5V. 12V would be nice.

The plan is for them to pass at least the LED If when they're on, and to keep the LEDS nice and bright I'd go for something with an Rds(on) of 100 milliohms or less.  That way, the transistors will only be stealing about 12 milliwatts or less from the LEDs and they'll (the transistors) stay nice and cool.

You can use Digi-Key's [filters](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/fets-single/1376381?k=MOSFET) to zero in on what you need and, if you actually want to build the thing, they've got the HC595s as well.

Here's how it works:

First, you send 96 bits of serial data into the shift register and then, after the 96th serial data clock, you assert the latch (frame) clock.

That'll broadside load all 96 of the data bits into their respective output latches, which will output the signals to the MOSFET gates, turning each of the 96 individual LEDs either on or off until the next frame clock comes along and updates the 96 LED array.

That way, as long as the frame rate is high enough there should be no perceptible flicker from the array.

So how to change colors?

By changing the relative brightness of the three colors in an LED RGB triad/pixel.

To do that, assume first a frame rate of 100 Hz to - for sure - get rid of any flicker.

100 Hz means that frame clocks occur every 10 milliseconds and then, since 96 bits have to be pushed into the shift register in 10 milliseconds, that means that the bit clock has to be going 96 times faster than 10 milliseconds, or 9600 Hz/bps.

Since there are 100 frames per second, and 96 bits per frame, that means that any bit in the array can be turned on or off 100 times per second, and that means that the longer it's ON, the brighter it'll be.

So, if all 3 LEDs in a pixel are OFF for, say, one frame, that pixel will be black but if they're all ON the pixel will be white.  Over a period of several frames, however, the 3 LEDs can be turned on for some of the time and off for some of the time, changing their apparent relative brightness, and that way change the perceived color from that pixel.

### POWER SUPPLY CONSIDERATIONS

PSU1 and PSU2 are the high-current supplies for the LEDs, and should be connected to the two columns separately, and then their grounds should be connected together.

Likewise, the arduino should be connected to its own supply and then the pair's grounds  connected to the common ground.

In order to keep the noise on the high current supplies from getting into the HC595s in the columns, a separate 5 volt supply should be used for that logic, and if it's available from the arduino, that can be used.

[image]

Comment: The leds OP is using are 3W RGBs, so 1W individual diodes. 350mA is the **upper constant current** limit of **each diode** in the RGB package. OP has updated their question to reflect that.

Comment: I saw that, and it's reflected in the updated LED current-limiting resistors on my edited schematic.

Comment: Your answer still shows 96 amps as full power draw tho

Comment: @EMFields many thanks for the circuit. I'm not sure if I understand the whole idea. I have some questions:  
- In some other similar circuits I've seen there is a resistor from Qx output to transistor's gate but you haven't draw any. Is that ok?  
- I've searched ebay for DMN2112SN-7 transistors. I didn't found many results. Can I replace it with something cheeper and more common? Any suggestions?

Comment: Also:   
- If I replace the 7.5 Ohm 2W resistor with 2x 15 Ohm 1W resistors in parallel or 4x 30 Ohm 1/2W resistors etc. This is to reduce the resistors cost. Is that ok?  
- Finally, if my calculations are correct the total power consuption will full brighness would be at least 168 watts with 33.6 Amps of currents. What should I use as a power supply for the lights and the arduino?  
Thanks

Comment: 1.There's an equivalent of about 100 ohms in HC outputs, so it probably isn't necessary.  It wouldn't hurt to leave space for one, though, you never know... 2. Any MOSFET with logic-level inputs and an Rds(on) of a couple hundred millivolts or less should be OK. 3. No problem with the resistors. 4. I'd use a separate 15 amp or so supply for each channel's LEDs and **DEFINITELY** a separate one for the arduino.

Comment: Why a seperate supply for arduino? My plan is to create 2 seperate columns with 16 leds each. It would be nice to have a power supply for each column + a power supply for arduino. I can't split the channels to different power supply. So how can I merge multiple PSUs into one circuit? Just by connecting their grounds output together?

Comment: All the arduino wants to do is to send out small signals to the MOSFET gates, but all around it is going to be this thing switching a lot of current and making a lot of noise, and if you use the same supply for the arduino that you do for the LEDs that noise is going to get into the arduino and give you grief.  Why can't you use a separate supply for each column?

Comment: Ok got it. I will use 2 20Amps PSUs for the 2 led columns and 1 third PSU for the arduino. I guess I should not forget to connect the PSU grounds together, right? The only foggy part of the project now is the transistors I'll use. I want an easy to find and cheap part. I don't know a lot about transistors types so I think I'll search for it. Any suggestions welcomed  
Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: I'll edit my answer sometime today to include power supply wiring information.  Arguably the best tools you can use to zero in on the MOSFETs are the Digi-Key and Mouser filters, located at their sites.  What you'll be looking for are N-channel enhancement mode MOSFETS with logic level gate inputs, a gate-to-source voltage (Vgs) of >5V, a drain-to-source ON resistance (Rds(on)) of a couple hundred milliohms or less, and whatever package you want.

Comment: A slightly disquieting thought: I've assumed the digital I/Os from your arduino are 0-5V.  Are they, or are they 0-3.3V?

Comment: I/Os are 0-5V. Thanks for everything man, I appreciate it ...
A new idea came in the meanwhile. I'll try to the make the led columns independend circuits having wireless communication (simple RFs maybe) with the main arduino controller. So each column may have a small arduino with a receiver in the same PSU. I think I could use some capacitors (with capacity?) to eliminate noise getting into arduinos and HC595s.

Comment: Or voltage regulators for noise elimination? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSzVs7_aW-Y

Comment: There's not much you're going to be able to put on the outputs of the big supplies, but you shouldn't have to since they're only feeding the LEDs.  The smaller ones are already regulated and are feeding much smaller loads, so their outputs won't dance around much anyway.  My advice is to go ahead and build it, keeping the power supply and signal wiring as short and as far away from each other as possible, then test it.  If it works, you're home free; if it doesn't, oh, well, that's what troubleshooting is all about. :-)

Comment: I'm searching around about transistors. Unfortunately I found out that there are lots of thing I don't know. I read somewhere that 2N2222 transistor is ok to use and using MOSFETs is an overkill. Some people also use the ULN2003 chip for one led but I'm not sure if it can handle the load with all pins used (It will save space in my circuit if I can use it). I'm a little bit lost here.  As for the noise issue, I'll definetely go for wireless columns with arduino on it. If the column has only one PSU I guess I should find a way to power up the arduino from there.

Comment: It sounds to me like you've gotten to the point where you need to start trying stuff. That is, get  some 2N2222s, MOSFETS, ULN2003s - whatever you think might work for you, and start wiring up some circuits and testing them.

Comment: 2N2222A transistors just arrived. I tested them but the led is hardly on by connecting it [this way](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_6/chpt_5/8.html) (with different resistor and power supply values). With the transistor on the circuit the current is about 4mA and without it, its 246mA. What's wrong?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I want to have full control of 32 (maybe 40) 6-pin 3W RGB LEDs from an Arduino Uno. By saying full control I mean to be able to adjust the brightness of each led independently.

You can use the PCA9685 IC, it is a 16 channels (LED) controller that is controlled via a i2c bus. The http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/PCA9685.pdf

A circuit description is:

From Arduino you have a i2c bus = 2 pins (sda, scl), thats sda = data and scl = clock signal.

On the i2c bus you can connect several PCA9685 IC's. To drive the LED's you need a MOSFET as LED driver.

A product that fit your need is maybee: 
http://ledsee.com/index.php/new-products/16-channel-i2c-fet-arduino-schield-pca9685-detail

Comment: Ohhh by the way there is arduino libraries availabe for PCA9685

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  
For my 32 leds I'll have 96 channel inputs (32 x3 for RGB). If the board has 16 I'll need 6 boards. I don't think it worth.  
Nice solution through ;)